# simplifyCFG pass in llvm

Tags: llvm, control-flow-graph

I was trying to run the simplify CFG Pass in LLVM , and delete an unreachable basic block after running one of my own IR transforms , but I keep getting the 
error -

**While deleting: i8* %g**

**Use still stuck around after Def is destroyed:  store i8 0, i8* %g**

I am well aware of what that means, but isn't the whole purpose of the "simplifyCFGPass" to delete the unreachable basic blocks for us ? Why must it then throw this error ? I would assume it should simply be able to manage all the use-def dependencies and delete the instructions in the unreachable "continuation" basic block below.

**Following is the relevant IR -**

```
entry:
  %a3 = alloca i32
  store i32 %a, i32* %a3
  %a4 = load i32, i32* %a3 
  %ifcond = icmp ne i32 %a4, 0
  br i1 %ifcond, label %then, label %else



then:                                             ; preds = %entry
  %gclone1 = alloca i32
  store i32 0, i32* %gclone1
  ret i5 0

else:                                             ; preds = %entry
  %gclone4 = alloca i64
  store i64 0, i64* %gclone4
  ret i5 0

continuation:                                     ; No predecessors!
  %iftmp = phi i32 [ 32, %then ], [ 64, %else ], !range !0
  %datasize = alloca i32
  store i32 %iftmp, i32* %datasize

  %g = alloca i8 ---------------------> Issue
  store i8 0, i8* %g ---------------------> Issue
  ret i5 0
}
```

Can someone please explain why this error crops up? Isn't the API supposed to handle this?

Comment: Does this error occur when you run your transformation or when you run simplifyCFGPass?

Comment: I run the CFG Pass ( using FPM->run(*F) ) 

 ... my pass is simply some C++ code that changes the IR, I am not using it in the opt tool or anything like that ...

Answer (score 0):

Your IR is clearly broken. You're having:

> %iftmp = phi i32 [ 32, %then ], [ 64, %else ], !range !0

However, per LLVM IR specification (http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#phi-instruction):

> The type of the incoming values is specified with the first type
>   field. After this, the ‘phi‘ instruction takes a list of pairs as
>   arguments, with one pair for each predecessor basic block of the
>   current block. Only values of first class type may be used as the
>   value arguments to the PHI node. Only labels may be used as the label
>   arguments.

This is clearly violated in your case and therefore the subsequent IR transformation passes might easily fail. I'd suggest you to run IR verification pass (e.g. via opt -verify) after your transformation pass.

Comment: Nope. I think I have clearly mentioned in the question "delete an unreachable basic block after running one of my own IR transforms".

The phi node is not broken ( and the verifier pass does not detect an issue )

Comment: The phi node is certainly broken. Neither %else nor %then are predecessors of %continuation